# ms access like ip addresses starts with sth

Tags: ms-access

In microsft access I got a table with fields username and ip
I want to select all rows that their ip addresses starts with 37.255.

I tried this but it didnt work:

```
select sheet1.username , sheet1.ip from sheet1 where sheet1.ip like '37.255.*'
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

By "I tried this but it didnt work:" you mean, you get no records back?

The SQL syntax looks good to me. Did you define [ip] as a text field? The LIKE clause would not work, if [ip] was a number.